# django coalesce return data type

Tags: python, django, coalesce

How `coalesce` determine the return data type of the attribute?

### USING

```
self.projects(
                select={"priority": "COALESCE(bm_rank, sales_rank, created_at)",

                },
                order_by=["priority"])
```

Its changing my float filed to the unicode string. I want to get float field in priority.

### EDIT

```
bm_rank = models.FloatField("Bizman Rank", max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)    
sales_rank = models.FloatField("Sales Rank", max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField("Date Submitted", auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Looks like you are coalescing two floats `bm_rank` and `sales_rank` with timestamp `created_at`. I might be wrong, but most likely `created_at` shouldn't be on the list. Btw, it might help if you post your database structure

Comment: Done. added the db structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are essentialy trying is to coalesce columns of different data types. You haven't specified your actual DB engine, but I can imagine only two sensible outcomes of such operation:

- Throw error, which is not your case
- Cast both columns' data types to common ancestor, if such ancestor exist, or to string type otherwise

Looks like in your case it's second option.

If you are trying to order by `bm_rank` then by `sales_rank` then by `created_at` you actually can do it without coalescing at all using [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra), like:

```
self.projects(order_by=["bm_rank", "sales_rank", "created_at"])
```

Comment: Thank you, i was trying to `coalesce` different data type coloumns, After removing `created_at` and adding `id` worked for me. +1